# Createhardlink in managed code

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I'm developing an application that creates hundreds of thousands of hardlinks (this is the core feature of the application).

I use the parallel programming features that are now available in dotNET 4.0. This works really well. See example snippits below.

Either:

```
Parallel.For(from, until, delegate(int i)
{
    j += 1;
    fileIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(j * 0.001) + 1);

    //determine the hardlink files; we have to have an unique name for the hardlink for each individual hardlink
    fileName = fiArray[fileIndex].Name; //Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(textBoxFile.Text);
    destinationFileName = Path.Combine(textBoxDestination.Text, string.Concat(fileName, "_", i.ToString(), ".txt"));

    fr.CreateHardLink(destinationFileName, fiArray[fileIndex].FullName);
});
```

Or:

```
//loop that does the actual work
for (int i = 0; i < nudThreads.Value; i++)
{
    //determine the work package per task
    from = 0 + until + 1;
    until = (i * (Convert.ToInt32(HardLinks / ThreadNo))) + 1;
    var compute = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); //uit boek
        return Work(from, until, false);//todo: counter moet nog worden meegenomen
    }, tokenSource.Token);

    tasks.Add(compute);

    var displayResults = compute.ContinueWith(resultTask => UpdateControls(),
                             CancellationToken.None,
                             TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion,
                             ui);
    CheckedListBoxFiles.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " : Created the hardlinks for: " + displayResults + " files.");
    Application.DoEvents();

    var displayCancelledTasks = compute.ContinueWith(resultTask => UpdateControls(),
                                CancellationToken.None,
                                   TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled, ui);
    CheckedListBoxFiles.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " : Cancelled a task at: " + displayCancelledTasks + " files.");
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```

The question i have is this: CreateHardlink is part of Kernel32.dll and hence runs in UNMANAGED code. What i know about the parallel ctp is that parallel tasks have to run in managed code. 
Is there a managed alternative for createhardlink? Does anyone know how to create a hardlink in managed code and does anyone have any thougths about the parallel programming and using unmanaged code?

Comment: Just a small note... I realize this may not be all your code, but just in case: you are setting fileIndex,fileName and destinationFileName within parallel context, but it seems to be defined outside the context. This would lead to a race condition that could be hard to detect - near impossible if you don't check the errorcode after the kernel32-call.

Answer (score 1):

There's little point in trying to create hard links in a parallel fashion. This is not a CPU bound operation, it is I/O bound. I would not expect any performance benefit from this approach when compared against the naive serial approach.

Your question about managed and unmanaged code relating to hardlink creation is interesting. You must remember that any I/O access from managed code will at some point call into unmanaged code. The OS is not managed and the only way to create a hardlink is to go through the OS. I think you need to be more precise about exactly what this restriction of the CTP to managed code really means.

Comment: The reason i use parallel programming is that the app also needs to keep track of some soap calls and we want to be able to  interrupt the hardlinkcreation if it locks at some point. Using parallel tasks, it is possible to catch whatever exception and act on it.

Comment: OK, I'd assumed that you were trying to gain a performance benefit on multi-core machines.

Comment: The trouble with creating hardlinks is that this stalls for some reason when you create them multi threaded.this is probably caused by the fact that the processing is faster than the disk IO can deliver. So excemptionhandling of the parallel tasks and the cancellationtoken features come in handy in such a situation.

Comment: By stalls I think you mean that the creation task hangs. If this is so then there will almost certainly be a threading bug in your code. I bet you don't get any stalls if you create the hardlinks in a single threaded mode.

Comment: Yes, when it was single threaded, it didn't have the locking problems, however, performance was really poor. Introducing multi threading did speed up the hardlink creation significantly, but sometimes, not always, the hardlink creation hangs (remember, we sometimes have to create up to a million hardlinks, often by several concurrent users)

Comment: Just a couple of comments on this discussion: There is always a limit to how many concurrent operations (of anything) you can run before the process comes to a halt. Instead of hardlinking that many files, can you use the shadow copy feature in the OS?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to cancel hardlink creation, but don't want multithreading, what I would do is implement a producer/consumer queue - one or more threads add "create a hard link at this path" work items to the queue, and a single thread grabs work items from the queue and creates hard links for them.

This gives you some flexibility over cancelling - you can abort the worker thread if you want to stop all hardlink creation, or if you want to cancel just one item you can find it in the queue and remove it.

Side note from looking at the code you posted - calling Application.DoEvents() is pure, unmitigated evil. Every time you call it, a baby seal clubs itself to death. A much better way to do it is for your UI to [queue a work item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem.aspx) on the thread pool, then use [Dispatcher.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx) (assuming this is WPF - if it's Winforms I know there's an equivalent but I don't know what it is) to update the UI asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Using unmanaged OS calls in parallel is no more a problem than doing it from managed code. Simple as that. :)

Managed code simply means it runs within a managed context (so the CLR can keep track of things). Execution wise it doesn't matter if it is managed or unmanaged.

If I am not remembering it wrong any kernel32-call is atomic, meaning it is thread safe.